# Set custom number for timeout response in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, timeout

Currently, whenever a timeout happens, a response with http status code 500 is issued by the runtime... i would like to change that number to 567 for example... how can I do that?

**Edit 1**:
I'm specifically trying to "manage" the exception returned when, on the web.config, you set `<httpRuntime executionTimeout="30" />` and on the code you do a `Thread.Sleep(60000);`(1 min to make sure the exception happens... there's a little uncertainty about that timeout...)

Comment: What kind of Timeout? There are execution timeouts, request timeouts, connection timeouts, DB query timeouts.... Can you provide some code to reproduce? I wasn't able to reproduce with a simple `Thread.Sleep...`.

Comment: There is no 567 status code.

Comment: @ChrisPratt i know that theres not... and thats the point...

Comment: @thmshd check it out

Comment: How is that the point? You're violating the spec, so it's a crapshoot how individual clients might handle that. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: If you're just trying to capture the fact that a timeout occurred instead of a general server error, you could use something like 408 Request Timeout or 599 Network Connection Timeout

Comment: @ChrisPratt ok chris... as long as it's not some code that another part of the framework issues... this is a LOB app, so no one else uses our "api" but us...